# Spring boot connect to MongoDB replica set running with an Arbiter

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, replication

My application is a Spring boot application and the application configuration properties file look like:

```
....
spring.data.mongodb.host=ip
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.admin.database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.database=myDB
spring.data.mongodb.username=su
spring.data.mongodb.password=su1$
....
```

Now the thing is for high availability MongoDB has been moved to a *Primary-Secondary-Arbiter* setup.
What changes should I do in order to connect to this. Tried separating with comma but that did not help.

Comment: Which version of mongodb? 2 or 3?

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 3.2.5

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Spring Boot [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connecting-to-mongodb) states:

> `spring.data.mongodb.host` and `spring.data.mongodb.port` are not
>   supported if you’re using the Mongo 3.0 Java driver. In such cases,
>   `spring.data.mongodb.uri` should be used to provide all of the
>   configuration.
>
> You can set `spring.data.mongodb.uri` property to change the URL and
>   configure additional settings such as the replica set.

Suppose you have replica set named `mc` with `mongo1:27017` as *Primary*, `mongo2:27017` as *Secondary* and `mongo3:27017` as the *Arbiter*, then you can use:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://su:su1$@mongo1:27017,mongo2:27017/myDB?replicaSet=mc
```

Please note [that](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.replicaSet):

> When connecting to a replica set it is important to give a seed list
>   of **at least two mongod instances**. If you only provide the connection
>   point of a single mongod instance, and omit the `replicaSet`, the client
>   will create a standalone connection.

Using MongoDB connection string you can set other properties such as *Read Preference*. Take a look at MongoDB [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) for more details.

Comment: Can we not use the properties mentioned in the question and still achieve it?

Comment: You won't need those configurations. Yes you can

Comment: `spring.data.mongodb.host` and `spring.data.mongodb.port` are not supported if you’re using the Mongo 3.0 Java driver. In such cases, `spring.data.mongodb.uri `should be used to provide all of the configuration.

Comment: i am using:<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
   <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.2</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: and spring.data.mongodb.host and spring.data.mongodb.port  are working on a standalone setup

Comment: You're using a 3+ java driver, then use the `spring.data.mongodb.uri`

Comment: i have the following proprties:
#spring.data.mongodb.host=
#spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
#spring.data.mongodb.admin.database=admin
#spring.data.mongodb.database=MyDb
#spring.data.mongodb.username=su
#spring.data.mongodb.password=su1$
how so i specify all this in URI

Comment: `mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]`

Comment: getting error host and port should be specified in host:port format

Comment: How did you specify them?

Comment: spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://su:su1$@ip1:27017,ip2:27017‌‌/myDB

Comment: ok got rid of the above problem however getting expecting replica set member, but found a STANDALONE, shall i also add the ip of arbiter node?

Comment: Set `replicaSet` option equal to your replica name as i did in the answer `spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://su:su1$@mongo1:27017,mongo2:27017/myDB?replicaSet=mc`