# Unable to establish connection with MongoDB Three Member ReplicaSet (PSA) in Google Cloud Platform from Spring Boot app

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, replicaset

I have set up **MongoDB (4.4)** using **click-to-deploy** in **google cloud platform**, three member replica set **(PSA) primary-seconday-arbitier** architecture. Now I am trying to establish a database connection from my **Spring Boot** app as shown :-

```
spring:
  data:
   mongodb:
       uri: mongodb://username:password@34.25.16.18:27017,34.05.83.26:27017/test?authSource=admin&replicaSet=rs0
```

where

- **34.25.16.18** is my primary **"mongodb-dev-servers-vm-0"**
- **34.05.83.26** is seconday **mongodb-dev-servers-vm-1**

> **Note :-** I have already added **firewall rule** to allow **TCP** for port 27017 for ip range **0.0.0.0/0** for all compute engine instances

Below given is the `rs.status()` :-

```
"set" : "rs0",
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(14),
    "syncSourceHost" : "",
    "syncSourceId" : -1,
    "majorityVoteCount" : 2,
    "writeMajorityCount" : 2,
    "votingMembersCount" : 3,
    "writableVotingMembersCount" : 2,
    "members" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "name" : "mongodb-dev-servers-vm-0:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 1,
                    "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                    "syncSourceHost" : "",
                    "syncSourceId" : -1,
                    "electionTime" : Timestamp(1629393549, 1),
                    "electionDate" : ISODate("2021-08-19T17:19:09Z"),
                    "configVersion" : 4,
                    "configTerm" : 14,
                    "self" : true,
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "name" : "mongodb-dev-servers-vm-1:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 2,
                    "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                    "syncSourceHost" : "mongodb-dev-servers-vm-0:27017",
                    "syncSourceId" : 0,
                    "configVersion" : 4,
                    "configTerm" : 14
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "name" : "mongodb-dev-arbiters-vm-0:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 7,
                    "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
                    "syncSourceHost" : "",
                    "syncSourceHost" : "",
                    "syncSourceId" : -1,
                    "configVersion" : 4,
                    "configTerm" : 14
            }
        ]
```

Below is **monogd.conf** :-

```
    net:
      port: 27017
      bindIp: 0.0.0.0
    
    replication:
      replSetName: rs0
```

Now when I am trying to deploy the spring boot app , I am getting this error :-

```
2021-11-30 15:12:28.635  INFO 18112 --- [  restartedMain] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : No server chosen by com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@24d2557c from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=mongodb-dev-servers-vm-1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: No such host is known (mongodb-dev-servers-vm-1)}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (mongodb-dev-servers-vm-1)}}, ServerDescription{address=mongodb-dev-servers-vm-0:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongodb-dev-servers-vm-0}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: mongodb-dev-servers-vm-0}}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
2021-11-30 13:47:19.874  INFO 5320 --- [vers-vm-1:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongodb-dev-servers-vm-1:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongodb-dev-servers-vm-1
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:211) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:75) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:143) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mongodb-dev-servers-vm-1
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:883) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:203) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2021-11-30 13:47:19.874  INFO 5320 --- [vers-vm-0:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongodb-dev-servers-vm-0:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: No such host is known (mongodb-dev-servers-vm-0)
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:211) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:75) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:143) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (mongodb-dev-servers-vm-0)
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:203) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2021-11-30 13:47:19.876  INFO 5320 --- [ters-vm-0:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongodb-dev-arbiters-vm-0:27017
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:-**

> **I am able to establish connection if instead of using both primary and seconday external IPs , I just use primary**
> **i.e -**

```
spring:
  data:
   mongodb:
       uri: mongodb://username:password@34.25.16.18:27017/test?authSource=admin
```

Comment: It can not resolve host name "mongodb-dev-servers-vm-0". If you define it into etc/hosts, then you can solve it. Most probably your application.yaml is wrong.

Comment: Your yaml file looks like: mongodb://username:password@mongodb-dev-servers-vm-0,mongodb-dev-servers-vm-1/test?authSource=admin

Comment: let's say , for now I want to test establish connection locally using the external IPs to GCP @Gurkanİlleez

Comment: Can you try replicaSet=rs0 in your connection. Please refer the  post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342401/spring-boot-connect-to-mongodb-replica-set-running-with-an-arbiter

Comment: I did. Still not working